# Winding mutiple axis coil

Tags: coil, winding

Wire coils can be used to 'pick up' alternating magnetic fields as described by Faraday's law.  I want to do this in multiple axes around a single core.  How could I do this in practice at a reasonable cost?  I have seen 'transponder coils' that do this in a small package (e.g. Premo, Neosid, Coilcraft, Murata):

[image]

I realized that placing the core on a simple coil winding machine will not work after the first axis if the winding axis has to go through the bobbin:

[image]

Therefore, I am considering either making a rotatable "end cap" that the end of a simple coil winder can be pressed against, or possibly winding each axis on a single-axis bobbin and then transplanting to the multi-axial bobbin.  However, in the latter case I am skeptical that dimensions would match up well and that the coil would stay together.  (Assume 1000 turns of 32 AWG wire.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put holes into the bobbin into which 'forks' would be inserted to straddle the previous coil(s) and provide an axis of rotation, either from one side or from both. Eg.

[image]